# in java, HashMap getKey() why I have to call toString to have string type?

Tags: java

For example I have hashMap which type is `<String,Integer>`
I call getKey from iterator, wanted to get String directly from the result.
But I found out that I have to call toString() to get  a string type. Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe you.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It should be fine, but we can't tell what you're doing wrong because you haven't shown us any code. My guess is that you're using the raw `Map.Entry` type, but that's only a guess at the moment.

Comment: You call `getKey` on *what* iterator?

Comment: yes, I am using this iterator : Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next(); is this wrong?

Comment: Raw Types!!! 'nuf said..

Comment: I've already voted to close, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) is what I would use as a duplicate.